# javascript doesn't change color of span container

Tags: javascript, css

i'm trying to change my span's text color using`document.getElementById("indicator").style.color = "red";`

and logs

```
console.log(document.getElementById("indicator").style.color);
```

tells me that it changes,but color still "black"

I'm using different css and bootstrap aswell in the project.
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: So basically the style changes, but you still see black color on your screen? Seems unlikely, unless you have other styles set with `!important` that is overriding it.

Comment: I'm not using !important in my own css file.Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you post your CSS file? What happens if you try to load the page without your CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your script is being called after the DOM item has loaded. If using jQuery you can simply wrap your function inside a document ready tag like this:

```
$(function(){
document.getElementById("indicator").style.color = "red";
})
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5jqhf7hz/

If you are using pure JavaScript you will need to make sure the script is listed after the DOM element. Putting the script at the end of your page should accomplish this.

Answer (score -2):

I just tested this on my IDE and got red text. You might want to check that your HTML Tag has the appropriate Tag ID of "indicator", as the syntax is correct. Also make sure your HTML page is linked to your Javascript page.

Put your JS page at the bottom of your HTML.

```
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

Edit: I just realized you were using bootstrap. I used bootstrap plenty of times and had trouble with the CSS of it. Basically the webpage puts Bootstrap CSS as priority. The only way to rewrite it from what I have found is:

1. Go into the Bootstrap CSS and put what color you want. (Not advisable).
2. Write more descriptive and narrower CSS. The more descriptive you are, the more CSS will put your code above bootstraps CSS.

Comment: Not a helpful comment, no example and no fiddle.

Comment: Atleast I answered. No one else has seem to have helped.

Comment: I'm trying to change my color using js,i have no style for this in my css file.

Comment: As mentioned before, Bootstrap is over-riding any CSS styles you put that are not more descriptive in length. You could try this

span #indicator {color:red;} in your CSS file.

Comment: This issue has been solved, please see answer above with working fiddle and code.